# tnsping resolves but not able to connect using script

Tags: r, oracle11g, rodbc

I am not able to connect to an oracle database from my R/Python scripts. Following is the code. TNSPing utility is able to resolve the database using LDAP. I am pasting TNSPING output as well.

**TNSPing output**

```
C:\Windows\System32>tnsping UHK00500_SECCOMPAS_APPL

TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 12-APR-2
013 10:26:26

Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
c:\apps\oracle\network\admin\sqlnet.ora

Used LDAP adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (SDU = 8192) (TDU = 8192) (ADDRESS_LIST = (
ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = PHKLOD2002-SCAN.ap.hedani.net)(PORT = 1522)) (
LOAD_BALANCE = on) (FAILOVER = on ) ) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = UHK00500_S
ECCOMPAS_APPL.WORLD) (FAILOVER_MODE = (TYPE = session) (METHOD = basic) (RETRIES
 = 20) (DELAY = 5))))
OK (60 msec)
```

**R script output**

**Oracle 11g driver**

> chan <- odbcDriverConnect("driver=Oracle in     OraHome112_32;DBQ=UHK00500_SECCOMPAS_APPL;UID=toolkit;PWD=******")
>       Warning messages:
>       1: In odbcDriverConnect("driver=Oracle in OraHome112_32;DBQ=UHK00500_SECCOMPAS_APPL;UID=toolkit;PWD=******") :
>         [RODBC] ERROR: state 08004, code 12154, message [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
>   2: In odbcDriverConnect("driver=Oracle in OraHome112_32;DBQ=UHK00500_SECCOMPAS_APPL;UID=toolkit;PWD=******") :
>     ODBC connection failed

**ODBC driver output**

> chan <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=UHK00500_SECCOMPAS_APPL;Uid=toolkit;Pwd=******")
>   Warning messages:
>   1: In odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=UHK00500_SECCOMPAS_APPL;Uid=toolkit;Pwd=*****") :
>     [RODBC] ERROR: state 08001, code 12154, message [Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle][Oracle]ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
>   2: In odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=UHK00500_SECCOMPAS_APPL;Uid=toolkit;Pwd=******") :
>     ODBC connection failed

Can someone please advice what i should check here to correct this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what the issue was, but after restarted my R instance the connection was fine.